# Calculating $\lim_{t\to\infty} \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{t}} e^{-z^{2}}f(t+z)dz$

Tags: integration, limits, analysis

I am trying to figure out what is the value of $$\lim_{t\to\infty} \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{t}} e^{-z^{2}}f(t+z)dz$$ where $f$ is continuous function. I want to conclude that the limit is zero because $\lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{1}{t}=0$ and so $\int_{0}^{0}e^{-z^{2}}f(t+z)dz=0$ but this does not seem to be rigorous because there is also $t$ inside $f$ as well. In this case, I have no information about what exactly $f$ is.

How should I evaluate this limit in a rigorous sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends on $f$. It is $\infty$ if $f(z)=e^{z^{2}}$ and $0$ if $f$ is bounded and continuous.